# i want to show the number of instances for each attribute value in weka java

Tags: java, weka

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffLoader.ArffReader;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(
                    "C:\\Program Files\\Weka-3-8\\data\\weather.numeric.arff"
                )
            );
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArffReader arff = null;
        try {
            arff = new ArffReader(reader);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Instances data = arff.getData();
        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
        System.out.println("The number of attributes is  : " +data.numAttributes());
        for(int i= 0; i< data.numAttributes(); i++){
            if(data.attribute(i).isNominal()){
                s = data.attribute(i).name().toString();
                System.out.println(
                    "the " + s + " attribute is nominal and takes "
                    + data.attribute(i).numValues() + " values"
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above I am showing for each attribute the number of values that it takes, but i'd like rather to show values (Strings) that it takes 
I am working on the file **weather.numeric.arff**. 
here is the file description :

```
@relation weather

@attribute outlook {sunny, overcast, rainy}
@attribute temperature numeric
@attribute humidity numeric
@attribute windy {TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute play {yes, no}

@data
sunny,85,85,FALSE,no
sunny,80,90,TRUE,no
overcast,83,86,FALSE,yes
rainy,70,96,FALSE,yes
rainy,68,80,FALSE,yes
rainy,65,70,TRUE,no
overcast,64,65,TRUE,yes
sunny,72,95,FALSE,no
sunny,69,70,FALSE,yes
rainy,75,80,FALSE,yes
sunny,75,70,TRUE,yes
overcast,72,90,TRUE,yes
overcast,81,75,FALSE,yes
rainy,71,91,TRUE,no
```

Comment: can you post your output?

Comment: The number of attributes is  : 5.                                                                the outlook attribute is nominal and takes 3 values.                                  the windy attribute is nominal and takes 2 values.                                   the play attribute is nominal and takes 2 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the String values of the nominal attribute using this: `data.attribute(attributeNo).value(position)`

where `attributeNo`is the number of the attribute and `position` is an integer that indicates the position of the nominal value as defined in the `.arff` file.

e.g 
`data.attribute(0).value(0)` is attribute's outlook , sunny nominal value